# Cron expression for monitoring schedule on aws Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron

I can't find the right way to write my cron expression.

I want my function to be triggered every minutes everyday for 10 minutes at 19h20.

So it as to be triggered every minutes from 19h20 to 19h30 everyday.

I'm trying something like this but it's not working:

> cron(0/1 19-20 ? * * *)

but this will trigger I think from 19h20 to 20h right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [cron expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) to run *Every minute between 07:20 PM and 07:30 PM* is:

```
cron(20-30 19 * * ? *)
```

You can get help from pages like [this one](https://crontab.cronhub.io/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Omar but this will run the lambda all the time from 19h20 to 19h30 right ? And not every minutes ?

Comment: It will execute the lambda at 19:20, then at 19:21 and so on until 19:30. So the lambda will be called 11 times in total